# TypeError: db.collection(...).save is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to submit data with an html form and send the data to my mongodb database using nodejs/expres crud operations, but I am receiving the error:

> TypeError: db.collection(...).save is not a function

I have two files, server.js and index.html.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/quotes" method="POST"> 
         <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">  
         <input type="text" placeholder="quote" name="quote">  
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My mongodb db is "notesDB" and collection is "quotes"
server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var db

MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.ydyhg.mongodb.net/notesDB', (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database.db('notesDB')
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })


})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('quotes').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      console.log('saved to database')
      res.redirect('/')
    })
  })
```

The error in the title has many other solutions on stack overflow, the most popular being

> It's mongodb version error which you have installed in your project.
> You should run npm install mongodb@2.2.5 --save in your project

When I tried this I had 4 critical vulnerabilities in my code and multiple other errors to which I realized I should just use the most up to date version, so I do not like that solution.

The second solution that I tried was moving the crud opperations, namely the get and post under the mongodb connection, I tried this due to the other posts about this error being structured this way, which did not change anything:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.ydyhg.mongodb.net/notesDB', (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database.db('notesDB')
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
  
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))


    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
    })

    app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
        db.collection('quotes').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        console.log('saved to database')
        res.redirect('/')
        })
    })

})
```

I read some more about using client instead of database thus I replaced the database with client and tried that way, which resulted in the same error.
Since I got this code from a tutorial I went a head and downloaded the final version of the code from his github and booted up the project and it worked, thus I am looking extra hard for why this is not working since it definitely should be, the code is [here](https://github.com/zellwk/crud-express-mongo/blob/master/server.js) if that helps at all since the code is so similar but actually works.

Edit: I am getting the listening on 3000, its submission of the form that I am getting the error, just for clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.save() has been deprecated instead of that .save() you can use .insertOne() or .insertMany() or.updateOne({upsert:true})

You can write your code like below by replacing .save() with .insertOne()

```
app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('quotes').insertOne(req.body, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      console.log('saved to database')
      res.redirect('/')
    })
  })
```

For further CRUD operation you can follow below docs

https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/node-crud-tutorial/?_ga=2.210725788.862450187.1649763419-1339553468.1649528473&_gac=1.209527078.1649528473.EAIaIQobChMIt8KGr8yH9wIVg3ZgCh3-2gcdEAAYASABEgJH8vD_BwE

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `save()` method, you should use Mongoose instead of MongoDB. MongoDB doesn't have any save method. You can do `insert()`, `insertMany()`, or if you updated instead of `save()`, you can simply use `replaceOne()`.